# Unity Logic Error with the rotation of my car

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My code that was put in the FixedUpdate section to turn the car in my game only works while moving forward, why is this

```
 moveDivisor =(Mathf.Pow(movespeed, (float)1 / 3));
        if (movespeed > 0.1f || movespeed < -0.1f)
        {
            Vector3 rot = new Vector3(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y + 1 * turnspeed * movespeed / moveDivisor, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);
            Vector3 rot2 = new Vector3(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y - 1 * turnspeed * movespeed / moveDivisor, transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && movespeed > 0)
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rot);
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && movespeed > 0)
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rot2);
            }
            movespeed = movespeed / 1.05f;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you check two times for

```
 if( ... && movespeed > 0)
```

For the `A` key you probably rather wanted

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && movespeed < 0)
```

Since anyway only one condition can be true at a time I would make these `if-else if` to avoid redundant checks. Also test the `movespeed` value first - afaik it is cheaper then the `Input.GetKey`

```
if (movespeed > 0 && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
{
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rot);
}
else if (movespeed < 0 && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
{
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rot2);
}
```